# log files prevent clean root umount

Tags: 13.10, mount, network-manager, upstart, init.d

My root fs is always dirty after shutdown. To see why, I added a couple of lines into `/etc/init.d/umountroot`:

```
/usr/bin/lsof / | /usr/bin/awk '$4 ~ /[0-9].*w/'
... mount -o remount,ro ...
/bin/bash </dev/console >/dev/console 2>&1
```

Here's the output:

[image]

If I create a symlink: `/var/log/upstart/mountall.log -> /dev/null` and manually kill `dhclient` before shutdown, the problem goes away.
``